# Angular 5+ cannot save result form observable response

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable, subscription

I have an Angular app which consumes data from a webapi.
When i make a request then i get an typed observable.

now when i do this:

```
data: Product[];
productService.getByProductId("061000957").subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.data = res;
});
console.log(this.data);
```

what i see in the console i can see this

[image: console screenshot]

I can clearly see, that the result has the Product i need.
But why cant i save this to my local variable data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observable is asynchronous just like promise. So `console.log(this.data);` is executed before the response is returned . Try .

```
data: Product[];
productService.getByProductId("061000957").subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.data = res;
       console.log(this.data);
    });
```

Now you print your data after it has been set.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with [async programming](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)  you cannot pause the execution of the code and your subscription will be resolved in future but you cannot predict when.  `console.log()` outside the subscribe is  executed before your subscription is resolved
  what you can do is You can store the value in a class property  inside subscribe callback .Refer [this](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/introduction-observables-angular-developers/) for better understanding.

```
   data: Product[];
productService.getByProductId("061000957").subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.data = res;
       console.log(this.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the data in the HTTP Observable subscription:

```
productService.getByProductId("061000957").subscribe(res => {
   this.data = res;
   console.log(this.data)   //you can see
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this , finally here will execute after getProductId is complete

```
productService.getByProductId("061000957")
      .finally(() => console.log(this.data))
      .subscribe(res => {
           console.log(res);
           this.data = res; 
    });
```

I use **do and finally** when I try to debug rxjs observable